# Would you give me a hand with these dishes?

Tags: exam-questions

Would you give me a hand with these dishes?
Which answer is correct:

> a. of course
>   b. yes, I would

This question appears in my exam, I am confused because I really think both are correct but then I have to choose one. So what do you think is the best answer.

Comment: What has prompted you to ask this question? Is it part of a test? Which answer do you think is correct? And why do you think the other one is wrong - if it is wrong at all? We expect you to do some research yourself.

Answer (score 3):

*Would you?* here is a polite way of saying *Will you?*, so the answer is "Of course" (or "Yes", "OK" or similar).

"Yes, I would" would be the appropriate answer if the question was about a hypothetical situation. "Would you like to go to China if you had the chance?" "Yes, I would."

Comment: I agree with Kate Bunting but I would add that my wife often makes requests such as: **Would you please throw out and dish water?** and I reply: **Yes, I would, with pleasure**. It may be an unusual response but it's both polite and perfectly grammatical.

Comment: Yes, there's a comical and endearing aspect to answering in that way. But "of course" is the more typical reply.